# facebook share how to get contents from url only?

Tags: facebook, share, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using facebook share functionality.

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URL&image=IMAE&description=DESC.
```

But it taking description, url and contents from open graph tags. I dont want to use contents from OG tags. but i cant remove og tags from head.

Same thing happening with linked and twitter.
Please give solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Share dialog does not accept any additional parameters besides the URL to share any more, and takes everything else from the OG meta tags.

The [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.4) still allows you to specify those values at runtime though; and making the post via API does too (but the latter requires the user to login to your app and grant it permission first.)

Comment: Thanks. I am going to implement API.